# nfs4: how to log mount requests?

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

On nfs3 we've had `rpc.mountd` which logged nice messages to syslog like

`authenticated mount request from 192.168.1.11:839 for /mnt/music (/mnt/music)`

nfs4 is quiet silent by default. I wish I could log authenticated and more important unauthenticated mount requests (including client IPs)

I've played around with `rpcdebug`, trying all kind of modules and flags but usually it logged too much and client IPs were not shown.

Answer (score 3):

NFSv4 does not have an explicit MOUNT operation. You can just watch traffic for SETCLIENT_ID operation for NFSv4.0 and EXCHANGE_ID for v4.1 and higher. Well, there are no official way to do it. But.... There is sqlite db in /var/lib/nfsnfsdcltrack/main.sqlite with a table clients, where you can find your clients:

```
$ sudo sqlite3 /var/lib/nfs/nfsdcltrack/main.sqlite "select * from clients"
Linux NFSv4.1 xxxxxxx|1486574417|1
$
```

where **xxxxx** is the client name/ip

**BEAWARE** that modifying the content of the database will end-up with non functional nfs server.

Comment: Wow, that's already really nice! Still missing the part how to see it on the server when client gets```mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting server:/path/...```